# Docker volume error read-only file system\\\"\"": unknown

Tags: docker, docker-compose

### Context

I am experiencing something strange while integrating **promtail** to my stack

```sh
ERROR: for asmodius_promtail  Cannot start service promtail: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:449: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/var/lib/docker/volumes/asmodius_nginx-logs/_data\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f6e22c4d99f1e9907a8ff4b05338386a38b9a7cd802944a877102bb805b97dac/merged\\\" at \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f6e22c4d99f1e9907a8ff4b05338386a38b9a7cd802944a877102bb805b97dac/merged/var/log/nginx\\\" caused \\\"mkdir /var/lib/docker/overlay2/f6e22c4d99f1e9907a8ff4b05338386a38b9a7cd802944a877102bb805b97dac/merged/var/log/nginx: read-only file system\\\"\"": unknown
```

The **volume** mentioned in this error is the one I use so promtail could read Nginx logs. (It only reads the files and does not need to write anything in the dir) Here is a portion of the `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  nginx: 
    container_name: ${SERVER_NAME}_nginx
    restart: always
    networks: 
      - monitoring
      - web
    image: nginx:1.17.5-alpine
    entrypoint: /entrypoint.sh
    ports: 
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes: 
      - ./nginx/site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
      - ./nginx/entrypoint.sh:/entrypoint.sh
      - nginx-logs:/var/log/nginx
      - certificates:/etc/letsencrypt/

  promtail: 
    restart: always
    container_name: ${SERVER_NAME}_promtail
    image: grafana/promtail:master-b652f0a
    command: -config.file=/etc/promtail/docker-config.yaml
    volumes: 
      - nginx-logs:/var/log/nginx
      - /var/log:/var/log:ro
      - ./promtail/docker-config.yaml:/etc/promtail/docker-config.yaml:ro
    networks: 
      - monitoring
```

and the volume "*inspection*"

```
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2020-04-28T20:08:41Z",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.project": "asmodius",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.24.1",
            "com.docker.compose.volume": "nginx-logs"
        },
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/asmodius_nginx-logs/_data",
        "Name": "asmodius_nginx-logs",
        "Options": null,
        "Scope": "local"
    }
```

Strangely enough, the very same `docker-compose.yml` works like a charm on my Debian 9

- Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b7f0
- docker-compose version 1.22.0, build f46880fe

but fails on CentOS

- Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b
- docker-compose version 1.24.1, build 4667896b

### Leads

I don't quite believe that docker-compose version could be the problem. I tried the following

- stop the entire stack, **rm** `nginx-logs` volume and start again
- use `:ro` not use `:ro`

### Questions

Since I do not entirely understand the `ERROR` message, an explanation of the following elements might help me figure what I am doing wrong.

- `read-only file system\\\"\"": unknown`: I just don't get what `"\"` is
- why does it mention a `merge` ? A merge with what?
- `mkdir`.... so it tries to create a folder somewhere in `/var/lib/docker`. But why does it have to do so for this specific volume while all the others (and there is quite a lot of them) succeed every time I `docker-compose up -d --force-recreate` (for it is how I add/update services on this machine)

All insights are welcome

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> mkdir /var/lib/docker/overlay2/f6e22c4d99f1e9907a8ff4b05338386a38b9a7cd802944a877102bb805b97dac/merged/var/log/nginx: read-only file system\\\"\"
> ```

This is complaining that it cannot create a directory under `/var/lib/docker`. None of that filesystem should be read-only. Perhaps you didn't start the docker engine as root, or perhaps there's something wrong with the filesystem itself. I'd double check that you haven't run out of capacity, either in free bytes or free inodes, with:

```
df /var/lib/docker/.
df -i /var/lib/docker/.
```

If you are running Docker Desktop, then as a last resort, destroy and recreate the docker VM. This will result in losing all the volume data, built images, running cntainers, etc, so backup anything you want to save.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit late but I battled with similar issue:

I believe the issue is caused by having two (container-internal) mount locations being overlaid but simultaneously having differing 'read-only' and 'read-write' permissions.

In the original post, you'll notice that for `promtail` service has these two mounts:

```
volumes: 
  - nginx-logs:/var/log/nginx
  - /var/log:/var/log:ro
```

here the first mount is mount is read-write, but second is read-only.

Note that

1. from the container's perspective the `/var/log/nginx` is **inside** `/var/log/`.
2. If the mount path inside the container (and/or volume) does not exist, docker will attempt to create it
3. it seems that docker will attempt to mount the paths from "top to bottom" from directory hierarchy perspective, not in the order they were listed in the `docker-compose.yml`.

This means that `/var/log/` will be mounted first, `/var/log/nginx` will be attempted second. If the `nginx` subdirectory does not already exist (very likely), then obviously it cannot be created if `/var/log` is marked read-only.

The error message attempts to inform user of this, but in rather confusing, un-intuitive way.

The easiest solution is to not mark parent directories (inside container) read-only if any children are intended to have write permission.

Another solution is to ensure that `/var/log/nginx` path exists inside the backing medium (the `nginx-logs` volume in this case) before the service is started. However, this is rather cumbersome to ensure reliably, e.g in cases where you recreate the volume or move hosts.